# How can I redirect 2 buttons to different intents in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkmbe.png)

I put a listener on each button that takes me to different activities.
The login button works perfectly, but the register button stops the app when I click on it.

I've tried to put a `Toast` message in the `_btnreg listener`, and it worked...

I got this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.android.virtualshelter, PID: 24128
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.virtualshelter/com.example.android.virtualshelter.register}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.android.virtualshelter.register.onCreate(register.java:35)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6754)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

```
package com.example.android.virtualshelter;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;   
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
Button _btnreg, _btnlogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _btnlogin  = findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    _btnreg    = findViewById(R.id.btnreg);

    _btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    _btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

My register.java code

```
package com.example.android.virtualshelter;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity
{

SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Button _btnReg;
EditText _txtfname, _txtlname, _txtpass, _txtemail, _txtphone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    openHelper = new DatabaseHelper(register.this);
    _txtfname  = findViewById(R.id.txtfname);
    _txtlname  = findViewById(R.id.txtlname);
    _txtpass   = findViewById(R.id.txtpass);
    _txtemail  = findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
    _txtphone  = findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
    _btnReg    = findViewById(R.id.btnreg);

    _btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String fname = _txtfname.getText().toString();
            String lname = _txtlname.getText().toString();
            String pass = _txtpass.getText().toString();
            String email = _txtemail.getText().toString();
            String phone = _txtphone.getText().toString();
            insertdata(fname, lname, pass, email, phone);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "register successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

public void insertdata(String fname, String lname, String pass, String email, String phone)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_2, fname);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_3, lname);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_4, pass);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_5, email);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COL_6, phone);
    long id = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
 }
```

I expect to go to activity register.java, but the app is crashing

Comment: Use Android Debug Bridge (open Logcat tab in Android Studio) to see the exception stack

Comment: Is your register activity defined in your manifest?

Comment: Yes everything is defined

Comment: In `activity_register.xml` check if the id of the button is `btnreg`.

Comment: Why importing `import android.widget.*; ` instead of specific class. Is `R.id.btn_reg` really exists and belongs to a `Button`?

Comment: please, provide code also for `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Thank you my problem is solved, I just checked I used the same id in another activity...So most of you were right thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch is, you are not able find the button, causing a NPE when setting the listner. Could be that you don't have the button defined in `R.layout.activity_main`, but in a different layout.

Comment: Its id is btnreg in activity_main

Comment: Add a null check

Comment: I added this if (v != null )
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, register.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

Comment: It gave me ERROR

Comment: You have two activities. In `MainActivity` you are are looking for `R.id.btnreg` in `R.layout.activity_main` and in `RegisterActivity` you are looking for *same* button id in a different layout. I'd suggest to use/create different button id for different layout and try looking up the button with that id.